# Adding Site to Organization in Liferay using hook

Tags: liferay

I am trying to create a Site for the Organization when the Organization is created using hook and adding listener to Organization entity.

I created site using `GroupLocalServiceUtil` and set up `siteName = String.valueOf(org.getOrganizationId()) + "LFR_ORGANIZATION" + org.getName()` like in DB.

Also I have set `className` and `classPK` like it is done when you create site to organization in liferay, but nothing happens. Site creates successfully, but it isn't connected with the Organization.

UPD.
Liferay 6.1 GA1

```
public Group addSite(Organization org) throws PortalException, SystemException
{
    ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
    String siteName = String.valueOf(org.getOrganizationId()) + "LFR_ORGANIZATION" + org.getName();

    Group newSite = GroupLocalServiceUtil.addGroup(
            getDefaultUserId(),
            "com.liferay.portal.model.Organization",    // Class Name
            org.getOrganizationId(),                    // Class PK
            siteName ,                                  // Name
            "",                                         // Description
            GroupConstants.TYPE_SITE_PRIVATE,           // Type
            org.getTreePath(),                          // Friendly URL
            true,                                       // Site
            true,                                       // Active
            serviceContext);

    OrganizationUtil.addGroup(org.getPrimaryKey(), newSite);

    return newSite;
}
```

How can I create such an Organizational Site programmatically?

Comment: Can you post the exact call you're making and what version of Liferay are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Liferay 6.1, it appears that when you create an Organization there is already a backing group. That group may not be visible depending on the `boolean site` parameter you pass:

```java
OrganiztionLocalServiceUtil.addOrganization(
    long userId, long parentOrganizationId, String name, String type,
    boolean recursable, long regionId, long countryId, int statusId,
    String comments, boolean site, ServiceContext serviceContext)
```

To make that Site visible for pages, simply call:

```java
OrganiztionLocalServiceUtil.updateOrganization(
    long companyId, long organizationId, long parentOrganizationId,
    String name, String type, boolean recursable, long regionId,
    long countryId, int statusId, String comments, boolean site,
    ServiceContext serviceContext)
```

with `site` parameter set to `true`.